# Configure ms-teams video-chat before the meeting

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to configure, preview and test the video background-image or background-blur **before** calling someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `/testcall` to check your webcam is working and your audio is good (a bit like the old Skype Echo test), but it doesn't support background images or blurring. Other than that, I guess call a colleague to test the change?