# Configuring Advanced Video Settings in Microsoft Teams for Personal Use Before a Business Meeting

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm preparing for an interview hosted on Microsoft Teams for business, but I only have access to the personal edition of Teams for Windows 11 I want to ensure my video background is blurred with the best filtering/lighting before joining the meeting.

However, I've found that the personal edition doesn't offer an option to pre-configure these settings before the meeting starts. Is there a workaround or method to set up my video settings in advance, ensuring I can best present myself from the start of the meeting? It would be awkward to be tweaking the settings once the meeting has begun. General video settings on Windows 11 aren't going to be adequate, and [the suggestion to call a colleague isn't practical right now; perhaps as a last resort](https://superuser.com/questions/1572894/configure-ms-teams-video-chat-before-the-meeting)

[image: Teams for personal use, Windows 11 settings]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have chosen a background in Teams, it should stay for all
subsequent meetings until changed.
In addition, you can only change backgrounds from within a meeting.

So you can just
use "Meet now" to start a meeting and then dismiss the Invite dialog.

Now you may click on the 3-points menu and select "Background effect".
Select an image, an effect or use "Add new" to add another image.

Once the image or effect are selected, click Apply, and if all is
correct then Leave the meeting.

All your future meetings should use this same background.

[image]